# ClickOnce - Secure Alternative to ActiveX for Launching Local Application from IE?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, activex, clickonce

Need to have ASP.NET page running on intranet launch a local windows application (VB6 exe). Originally planning to use an ActiveX control, however general security concerns with ActiveX controls (real and perceptual) have led us to consider a ClickOnce approach to the problem. The user would click on a link that would launch the ClickOnce application (the ClickOnce application would just be a .NET windows app to launch the VB6 app). Is this a better solution from a security perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you couldn't simply publish the application that you want to launch as a ClickOnce application?

When a ClickOnce application is published, it always checks the server for any updates and, if there are none, it launches the cached installation of the application.  This is the same effect as the "launch" link on the default ClickOnce installation page that is generated when you publish the application.  You could publish the application and then copy the URL from the launch link to your website for the same effect.

I wouldn't recommend your method above.  I don't know your specific scenario but, obviously, your ClickOnce application that you mention above would not work if the VB6 application did not exist on the users computer or if it was located in a different installation location.

In response to your security concerns, I'm not an Active X expert but I wouldn't think launching an ActiveX component would be a problem if it's being used from within your intranet.  In fact, I think the problem with ActiveX is when it's enabled, malicious websites can inject harmful ActiveX viruses.  I'm not a security expert, so I could be wrong.  I'd be surprised, however, that hosting an ActiveX service would be a security problem (assuming your code is legit ;)